# How to write this SQL query for a XML type?

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, sql-server-2012, xquery

I am using SQL Server 2012 in which I have a table `[abc]` which  has  a column called `[Information]` of the `[XML]` type.

This column has values like -

```
<Information>
  <Groups>
    <Group Name="Monitor">
      <Items>
        <Item>
          <Name>Cid</Name>
          <Value>2323232323</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Name>Tid</Name>
          <Value>6656565656</Value>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </Group>
  </Groups>
</Information>
```

How can I write a SQL Query which can query this column - `[Information]` and further extract the value of `[Tid]` from the name /value?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @abc TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Information XML);
INSERT INTO @abc VALUES
(N'<Information>
  <Groups>
    <Group Name="Monitor">
      <Items>
        <Item>
          <Name>Cid</Name>
          <Value>2323232323</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Name>Tid</Name>
          <Value>6656565656</Value>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </Group>
  </Groups>
</Information>');
```

--This query fetches the one and only value (`<Value>`, where `<Name>` is "Tid") using an `XQuery` predicate

```
SELECT ID
      ,Information
      ,Information.value(N'(/Information/Groups/Group/Items/Item[Name/text()="Tid"]/Value/text())[1]',N'bigint') AS ValueInTid
FROM @abc AS abc;

--Result=6656565656
```

--This query uses `.nodes()` to get all (repeated) `<Group>` nodes, than again `.nodes()` to return (repeated) `<Item>` nodes. The result is a complete table:

```
SELECT gr.value(N'@Name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS GroupName
      ,itm.value(N'(Name/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ItemName
      ,itm.value(N'(Value/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ItemValue
FROM @abc AS abc
OUTER APPLY abc.Information.nodes(N'/Information/Groups/Group') AS A(gr)
OUTER APPLY A.gr.nodes(N'Items/Item') AS B(itm);
```

The result

```
GroupName   ItemName    ItemValue
Monitor     Cid         2323232323
Monitor     Tid         6656565656
```